# How to attach to a python function using Frida?

Tags: python, frida

I'm trying to figure out how to hook calls to functions inside a python program using Frida.

The python code below is the program that to be dived into

```
# hello.py
from time import sleep

def print_num(i=0):
    print(i)

print(f"print_num address: {print_num}")

i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    print_num(i)
    sleep(4)
```

And the hook script is just trying to attach to the `print_num` function with its address, then report back a result `i` every time it was get entered.

```
# hook.py
import frida
import sys

session = frida.attach("THE PID OF THE hello.py")
# replaced with the real print_num address
func_addr = "THE FUNC ADDR OF print_num"
script = session.create_script(
    """
    send("start injecting...");
    Interceptor.attach(ptr("%s"), {
        onEnter: function(args) {
            send(args[0].toInt32());
        }
    });
    """ % int(func_addr)
)

def on_message(message, data):
    print(message)

script.on('message', on_message)
script.load()
sys.stdin.read()
```

Result:

```
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'start injecting...'}
```

It seems that `hook.py` could properly address the `test.py` program but couldn't address the `print_num` function. Otherwise it should report something like

```
{'type': 'send', 'payload': '1'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': '2'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': '3'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': '4'}
...
```

So is it possible to attach to a python function with Frida? How to do that?